# Target column Encoding and output layer in Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning

For multiclass classification problem,

1. Is one hot encoding of target column necessary or we can use label encoded target column and just use the loss as "SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy"
2. The number of units in output layer is always equal to number of classes? Does it depends on type of encoding we are performing on target column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with RNNs ( sequential inputs ) , you can use SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy as loss (when the target aren't one hot encoded).